# Asynchronous and Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

I am new to ajax and am following Lynda "Javascript and Ajax" tutorial.Here is the problem i have come across.

I have a text document named "data" which has text HELLO WORLD saved on it.

My index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JavaScript AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript file is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'data.txt',false);
    request.send();
    console.log(request);
    document.writeln(request.responseText);

}
```

My question is when i do Synchronous XMLHttpRequest by giving argument false(on request.open() ), my browser displays "HELLO WORLD" 100 times as per the code.But as i try doing Asynchronous XMLHttpRequest by giving argument true or nothing as default, the browser doesnt display anything.Why is it so?

Could anyone please help me on this?I am grasping some knowledge on asynchronous and synchronous requests.What has these got to do with the code above acting differently?Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous calls don't prevent subsequent code execution. In your example, the console.log is running before the async request completes.

Using your code above as a guide, here is a working example.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.addEventListener('load', complete, false);
    req.open('GET', '/echo/json/', true);
    req.send();
}

function complete(e) {
    console.log(this.responseURL);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75eLfwz1/